# Has Many Through in django?

Tags: python, django, orm, relationship

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Tag(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How to use post object to get all tags???

Like laravel framework hasManyThrough?

> Except this way

```
for comment in post.comment_set.all():
    for tag in comment.tag_set.all():
        print(tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is reverse lookup, you can use `prefetch_related`.

```
Post.objects.filter(your_condition)
.prefetch_related(Prefetch("comment_set"),
 queryset=Comment.objects.prefetch_related("tag_set"))
```

You can set the querysets based on your conditions.